# Taking user prompt and applying them into a table with a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues with my JavaScript code and understanding JavaScript entirely in combination with HTML and CSS. It appears similar to programming in Java or C++, but I can't seem to get an output so I know it's different. It doesn't help that code editors point out errors due to it being confused between HTML syntax and JavaScript syntax. Here is my code below:

```js
var num1;
var num2;

var i;

var square;
var cube;
var min;
var max;


//prompts user to input 2 numbers and then converts the string into integers
//Returns those numbers
function prompt1() {

  do {

    num1 - window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
    number1 = parseInt(num1);

  }
  while (number1 < 1 || number1 > 20);
  return number1
}

function prompt2() {
  do {

    num2 - window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
    number2 = parseInt(num2);

  }
  while (number2 < 1 || number2 > 20);
  return number2;
}

//Compares the 2 numbers plugged in and then compares them to get range
function listRange() {
  if (number1 > number2) {
    max += number1;
    min += number2;
  } else {
    max += number2;
    min += number1;
  }
  return min, max;
}

//Creates a table and uses range to fill data
function myTable() {

  var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableDiv");

  table.Div.innerHTML = "<table>" +
    "<thead><th>Number</th><th>Square</th>" +
    "<th> Cube </th> </thead>" +
    "<tbody>" +

    for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {

      "<tr>< td>"

      number += i + "</td><td>" +
        square += i * i + "</td><td>"
      cube += i * i * i +
        "</td></tr>";
    } +
    "</tbody></table>";
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: ***Your code has far too many errors to fix.*** Please take the time to learn the very **basics** of Javascript before asking any more related questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it simply has far too many error to even **begin** commenting on that.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it further. Wasn't necessarily looking for a fix per say, just some clarification. I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think below is what you want. There are lots of error in your code.

1) A syntax error.

2) There is no div with id "myTableDiv"

3) you just defined functios but never call them.

4) in prompt1 and prompt2 you have syntex somthing like num - window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20"); which is wrong.

5) You are doing "" without assigning it to anyone in myTable() function.

And there are few mores(mostly syntex)

```js
var num1;
var num2;

var i;

var square;
var cube;
var min;
var max;


//prompts user to input 2 numbers and then converts the string into integers
//Returns those numbers
function prompt1() {
  do {
    num1 = window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
    number1 = parseInt(num1);
  }
  while (number1 < 1 || number1 > 20);
}

function prompt2() {
  do {
    num2 = window.prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 20");
    number2 = parseInt(num2);
  }
  while (number2 < 1 || number2 > 20);
}

//Compares the 2 numbers plugged in and then compares them to get range
function listRange() {
  if (number1 > number2) {
    max = number1;
    min = number2;
  } else {
    max = number2;
    min = number1;
  }
}

//Creates a table and uses range to fill data
function myTable() {

  var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableDiv");

    x = "<table>" +
    "<thead><th>Number</th><th>Square</th>" +
    "<th> Cube </th> </thead>" +
    "<tbody>";

    for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      x+="<tr><td>"+ i + "</td><td>" + i * i + "</td><td>" + i * i * i +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    x+= "</tbody></table>";
    tableDiv.innerHTML=x;
}
function init(){
  prompt1();
  prompt2();
  listRange();
  myTable();
}
onload=init;
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myTableDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input yajiv. I'm gonna study it a bit more, I was mostly pressing for time. I was trying to copy my professor's example or slides as far as the table goes and even the functions like window.prompt, which did work for me at one point in the code, but it just got confusing as his examples have <script> entirely in the <head> and it works vs W3 schools or other sites which uses executes in the <body>